# UPDATE mulitiple rows through trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created this trigger to update the amount of the Invoices. This is the payment table that holds the trigger.

**ci_payments**

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_payments` (  
        `payment_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
        `customer_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,  
        `payment_method` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
        `receipt_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
        `cheque_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
        `amount` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,  
        `payment_on` datetime NOT NULL,  
        `payment_note` mediumtext NOT NULL,  
        `current_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
        PRIMARY KEY (`payment_id`),  KEY `invoice_id` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the Inovice Table and Data:

[image: Invoice Table]

For example take the `Customer ID: 8` who has two invoices that has paid_amount `0.00` ; 
I am trying to update the amount of Invoice through trigger on payment table.

Let say Customer paid `400.00` so i want to update first invoice as `paid` and second as `partial` with the `paid_amount`;

This is the trigger i have created

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER uni_payment_updater AFTER INSERT ON ci_payments FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE amt_diff, t_amount DECIMAL(9,2);
DECLARE inv_id INTEGER;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select total_amount, invoice_id from ci_invoices where customer_id = new.customer_id and (status = "unpaid" or status = "partial") order by invoice_id asc;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

SET @uni_paid_amount := NEW.amount;

OPEN cur;
    ins_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO t_amount, inv_id;

            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;

            SET amt_diff = NEW.amount - t_total;

            IF amt_diff > 0.00 THEN
                UPDATE ci_invoices set paid_amount = amt_diff where invoice_id = inv_id;
            END IF;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;


END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But i am getting this error
`Unknown column 'uni_paid_amount' in 'field list'`

Anyone please help to correct where and what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot the @. Try SET amt_diff = @uni_paid_amount - t_total;

Comment: @KayNelson i tried in both `SET amt_diff = @uni_paid_amount - @t_total;` but i think `@` is ignoring the warnings. But now the result in not updated in `ci_invoice` table

Comment: What if you try and use the `NEW.amount` instead of a variable?

Comment: @KayNelson Didn't get any error, but nothing update in `ci_invoice`

Comment: Can we confirm that New.Amount actually has a value?

Comment: @KayNelson i tried with the value `200`, i have to fix the logic.

Comment: Do you continue his error after the change, `SET amt_diff = uni_paid_amount - t_total;` to `SET amt_diff = NEW.amount - t_total;`? You have defined the variable `t_total`?

Comment: @wchiquito I will update the logic section soon, and it's working with `SET amt_diff = NEW.amount - t_total;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Fixed query:

```
set @paid = 200;
update invoice i
set 
i.paid_amount = if(@paid <= total_amount, @paid, total_amount),
i.status = case when paid_amount = 0 then 'unpaid' when total_amount = paid_amount then 'paid' when paid_amount > 0 and paid_amount < total_amount then 'partial' else 'wtf' end,
i.id = if(@paid := if(@paid <= total_amount, 0, @paid - total_amount), i.id, i.id)
where i.customer_id = 16
order by id /*or whatever columns determines the order of the invoices*/
;
```

Tried it with following and it works now:

```
mysql> drop table if exists invoice;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table invoice (
    -> id int auto_increment primary key,
    -> customer_id int,
    -> total_amount decimal(10,2),
    -> paid_amount decimal(10,2) default 0,
    -> status varchar(50) default 'unpaid'
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into invoice (customer_id, total_amount) values
    -> (3, 0),
    -> (8, 303.75),
    -> (8, 200.00),
    -> (16, 303.75),
    -> (16, 200.00);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from invoice;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  4 |          16 |       303.75 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  5 |          16 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> set @paid = 400;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update invoice i
    -> set
    -> i.paid_amount = if(@paid <= total_amount, @paid, total_amount),
    -> i.status = case when paid_amount = 0 then 'unpaid' when total_amount = paid_amount then 'paid' when paid_amount > 0 and paid_amount < total_amount then 'partial' else 'wtf' end,
    -> i.id = if(@paid := if(@paid <= total_amount, 0, @paid - total_amount), i.id, i.id)
    -> where i.customer_id = 8
    -> order by id /*or whatever columns determines the order of the invoices*/
    -> ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from invoice;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |      303.75 | paid    |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |       96.25 | partial |
|  4 |          16 |       303.75 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
|  5 |          16 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> set @paid = 200;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update invoice i
    -> set
    -> i.paid_amount = if(@paid <= total_amount, @paid, total_amount),
    -> i.status = case when paid_amount = 0 then 'unpaid' when total_amount = paid_amount then 'paid' when paid_amount > 0 and paid_amount < total_amount then 'partial' else 'wtf' end,
    -> i.id = if(@paid := if(@paid <= total_amount, 0, @paid - total_amount), i.id, i.id)
    -> where i.customer_id = 16
    -> order by id /*or whatever columns determines the order of the invoices*/
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> select * from invoice;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |      303.75 | paid    |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |       96.25 | partial |
|  4 |          16 |       303.75 |      200.00 | partial |
|  5 |          16 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Original answer:**

You don't need a trigger at all, let alone a cursor (I always try to avoid those at all costs). You know the customer_id you just inserted into your payment table. Then fire this update statement after insert.

```
/*table serving as example*/
drop table if exists invoice;
create table invoice (
id int auto_increment primary key,
customer_id int,
total_amount decimal(10,2),
paid_amount decimal(10,2) default 0,
status varchar(50) default 'unpaid'
);

/*sample data*/
insert into invoice (customer_id, total_amount) values
(3, 0),
(8, 303.75),
(8, 200.00);

select * from invoice;

+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+

set @paid = 400;
update invoice i
set 
i.paid_amount = if(@paid - total_amount >= 0, total_amount, total_amount - @paid),
i.status = if(@paid - total_amount >= 0, 'paid', 'partial'),
i.id = if(@paid := @paid - total_amount, i.id, i.id)
where i.customer_id = 8
order by id /*or whatever columns determines the order of the invoices*/
;

select * from invoice;

+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |      303.75 | paid    |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |      103.75 | partial |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
```

If you insist on using a trigger, here's the same example with a trigger:

```
drop table if exists invoice;
create table invoice (
id int auto_increment primary key,
customer_id int,
total_amount decimal(10,2),
paid_amount decimal(10,2) default 0,
status varchar(50) default 'unpaid'
);

insert into invoice (customer_id, total_amount) values
(3, 0),
(8, 303.75),
(8, 200.00);

drop table if exists payment;
create table payment (
id int auto_increment primary key,
customer_id int,
amount decimal(10,2)
);

delimiter $$
create trigger pay after insert on payment for each row 
begin
set @paid = new.amount;
update invoice i
set 
i.paid_amount = if(@paid - total_amount >= 0, total_amount, total_amount - @paid),
i.status = if(@paid - total_amount >= 0, 'paid', 'partial'),
i.id = if(@paid := @paid - total_amount, i.id, i.id)
where i.customer_id = new.customer_id
order by id;
end $$
delimiter ;

select * from invoice;

+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |        0.00 | unpaid |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |        0.00 | unpaid |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------+


insert into payment (customer_id, amount) values (8, 400);

select * from invoice;


+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
| id | customer_id | total_amount | paid_amount | status  |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           3 |         0.00 |        0.00 | unpaid  |
|  2 |           8 |       303.75 |      303.75 | paid    |
|  3 |           8 |       200.00 |      103.75 | partial |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------+
```

Keep in mind though, that application logic is easier to handle and maintain in application code, rather than in database triggers.

Comment: I tried with the trigger with the amount `200` and its not working as i expected. Its update the values as according to your example

Comment: It's only working if we insert the value higher then paid amount, I tried with the value `400` and its working, but not with the `200` if i tried the 200 then the `paid_amount` should be 103.75 for first invoice as status partial, and skip the second options because the applied amount already added on first invoice.

Comment: @jogesh_pi Fixed my query. See edited answer, it works now in both cases.

Comment: I left this part for the next revision of script and added the logic in PHP, i will  update the code with next revision of my script.

Comment: Glad I could help. It was a bit of work, an upvote wouldn't hurt either ;)

Comment: Indeed that looks like a big solution. Upvote from me!